# Set projection for all features generated in PYQGIS script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, coordinate-system

I have a script that loops through input raster's creates new raster files and converts these to vector performing a number of additional processes. Ultimately a vector is created that is a modified version of the input raster.

My question is how can I ensure that each new raster and vector created, whether they are a temp file or the final output, maintain the same projection (ESPG 27700)? Is there a command I can add in at the start of each loop or can I set the output projection in each individual process e.g. raster calculator or polygonize. An example line of the script is provide:

```
out1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', raster,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1','A>0',None,5,None,result_shp + "/" + result_name)
```

Additionally, is it possible to set a snap raster in a similar way and is this something I should consider doing?

Comment: Are your input layers always in `EPSG:27700`?

Comment: They should be, but I've had examples where they have an undefined / user defined projection that differs. Perhaps the solution could be as simple as using one of the tools to define the projection on the initial input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use an `if` statement to check if the raster CRS is `EPSG:27700`. If it is then run your `gdalogr:rastercalculator`, otherwise reproject it first using `gdalogr:warpreproject` and then run `gdalogr:rastercalculator`.

---

For example, something like:

```
if raster.crs().authid() == 'EPSG:27700':
    out1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator',raster,'1',...)
else:
    out1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:warpreproject',raster,...)
    out2=processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', out1['OUTPUT'],'1',...)
```